# Why is ViewBag called ViewBag?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In asp.net mvc, why is ViewBag called ViewBag?

I'm looking for the history or reason why it's called ViewBag over some other name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ViewBag is a dynamic mapping of the ViewData dictionary.  It's called a "bag" because there's no order or sequence to it.. it's just a bunch of data accessible from a dynamic property, much like if you had a bag of stuff.

The underlying ViewData has order to it, but when it's mapped to the dynamic collection it loses that order.. thus it's a bag.

See a definition here:

http://www.cs.miami.edu/~geoff/Courses/MTH517-00S/Content/ArrayBasedADTs/BagsStacksQueues.html

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bag full of information which is made available to the view.

It enables you to dynamically share values from the controller to the view. It is a dynamic object which means it has no pre-defined properties. You define the properties you want the ViewBag to have by simply adding them to the property. In the view, you retrieve those values by using same name for the property.